# jquery - Select no children

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

given the html:

```
<div>
    <span class="a">a
      <span class="b">b</span>
    </span>
<div>
```

Is it possible to just select the first span and not it's children?

Calling `$('div span.a').text()` prints the 'b' in the child node as well as the 'a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var span1 = $("span.a").clone();
$(span1).children().remove();
var text = $(span1).text();
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably would be better off writing better structured html like:

```
<div>
    <span class="c">
      <span class="a">a</span>
      <span class="b">b</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

But you could do this:

```
var text = $('div span.a').clone().find('*').remove().end().text();
```

Comment: It's also worth adding a `.trim()` after the `.text()`, depending on how what you're passing it do deals with whitespace. Just ran into this myself and thought I'd mention it.